# char array starting point in a loop and the & mark

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, char

I was helping my brother in his programming homework so we came to a place where we have an array of integer so if you have 10 integers in a table a[10] and you want to place them in a reversed way you should do:

```
for(i=9;i>=0;i--)
{ 
printf("%d",a[i]);
}
```

I can understand that and its logic, but if you have a char then you should start with 10:

```
for(i=10; i>=0;i--)
{
printf("%c",a[i]);
}
```

what's the cause and why would it access the loop 11 times while the number of the letters is 10 so that it takes all the letters, I placed 9 instead of 10 and one letter was missing so what causes that in char[];

plus when do we add the & mark for example:
I declare

```
int a;
```

and I write:

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

I know that it's because we need to give the address of 'a' but please can anyone give more details and when do we write it without &? thanks.

Comment: can I get any help here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char string[] = "helloworld";
```

The length of that array is 11, not 10. (So the highest index is 10). It includes a NUL, '\0' on the end. You should however NOT print the NUL, so you should be starting at 9 still.

---

If you prefix a variable with an ampersand, it is passed by reference. Basically it means that whatever function you're using it with will be able to modify the variable (otherwise the function only gets a copy of the data).

It's also used to get the "address of" a variable (basically turn it into a pointer), usually for the same reason. That's used more in C than C++.

Comment: ok thank you but why the length of helloworld is 11 not 10? what I can see is 10 letters so why its length is 11 besides I added strlen("name") and got 4 not 5.. so still didn't understand this..

Comment: The length of a char array is the number of characters in it, plus one for a `NUL` at the end (which signifies "end of string"). `char person[]="name"` is exactly equivalent to `char person[] = {'n','a','m','e','\0'};` ---- HOWEVER, `strlen` (and various related functions) count the "printing length", i.e. they exclude the `NUL`.